# extract float values from a string

Tags: java, arrays

I have a long string like `"abc_12.23;dcf_23.99;dfa_12.99;` and so on.

Now i need to create a to seperate the float and the string values into a float and a string array respectively.

I tried with splitting them on ";" and took it in an array and then performed a split over "_" and extracted them in an array. But it was not working. Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: Unless you decide to use a real serialization, like JSON, that's a fine approach. Next question.

Comment: We don't know if you have _the best_ solution without seeing any code.

Comment: the best solution to a problem is usually the easiest one. if that solution is easy for you, then go for it

Comment: Another tool is Regex that will really over-complicate things. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @jlordo, solution and code are diferent. For me solution properly described.

Comment: If you want to validate the float values themselves, see http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/FloatValidator.html

Comment: @PLB: He is splitting, so he already is using regex ;)

Comment: @jlordo I meant using one regex pattern instead of splitting twice. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, using StringTokenizer might be more a little more efficient

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("abc_12.23;dcf_23.99;dfa_12.99", "_;");
    int n = st.countTokens();
    String[] sa = new String[n / 2];
    float[] fa = new float[n / 2];
    for(int i = 0 ; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
        sa[i] = st.nextToken();
        fa[i] = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You solution is good.

Followig approach a bit increase performance:

- Iterate all chars into string.
- When you found "_" or ";" copy substring from last same char (if
  current ; parsed is float, it _ than parsed is string) and push into
  appropriate array.

Not sure that your improve performance greatelly.

**Note:** I not java pro, but if java allow spilt by several chars just split by ";" and"_" and use odd indexes for floats and not odd for strings.

Comment: I not have java compiler =( If you want I can post on C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution:

```
    String input = "abc_12.23;dcf_23.99;dfa_12.99; and so on";
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)_(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?);?";
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> floats = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        strings.add(matcher.group(1));
        floats.add(Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
    }
    System.out.println(strings); // prints [abc, dcf, dfa]
    System.out.println(floats); // prints [12.23, 23.99, 12.99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
(\w.)_(\d.\.\d.);
```

Test it here [A Regular Expression Test Applet](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html)

Use `matcher.find()` to step through the matches.

Group 3 (index 2) will have the float value.

Answer (score 0):

You might use **Scanner**. It would look like this:

```
scanner = Scanner("abc_12.23;dcf_23.99;dfa_12.99;");
scanner.useDelimiter("[;_]");
while(scanner.hasNext()){
  String s = scanner.next();
  float f = scanner.nextFloat();
}
```